# pylibtiff for x64 windows, download or how do I compile the binaries?

Tags: python, build, compilation, tiff, windows-7-x64

I need to process a LOT of tif files (change their size, dpi and colorspace/colorprofile) and apparently pylibtiff is the way to go. I've tried PIL but that can't handle many of the tif files that pylibtiff supposedly can. My question is does anyone have the link to a precompiled binary for windows x64?

Or can anyone help me compile [this one](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/downloads/detail?name=tiff-3.8.2-1.exe&can=2&q=)?

...pls...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) are the the Windows 64 binaries (including pylibtiff).